# Establish a Connection with a Server using Android app

Tags: android

I have a web server that by username and password I can connect to it and retrieve data from it.

I need to connect this server from an Android app.

So far, I tried to post the username and password with HttpPost to the server. But, the server doesn't allow me to retrieve the data because we didn't make a connection.

Is there any way I can establish a connection with the server from my Android app in the same way as a web connection?

I guess it's called a "VPN connection".

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you post you code? It may be problem with values you sending to server

Comment: @Mr. Concolato Simple HttpPost with AsyncTask ...The server does response to it by an html page But than when im trying to retrieve the data from it it doesn't response since we didnt made any connection

Comment: @Vino the server does response to the HttpPost ther isnt any problem with the values ... But to retrieve the data from his database is not allowed since we didnt established any connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a web-service for that, just try to create a simple RESTful service in your web server.

First, you will create a Login service, pass your login credentials to it and retrieve a secure auth_key. For example: HttpPost -> Login: params(username, password); Response -> Login: auth_key="xxxx0000".

You use your `auth_key` to retrieve the data from your server (`auth_key` serves as the security for your data), in your Data service, you should require a valid `auth_key` as a param, so then it'll return your desired data. For example: HttpPost -> Data: params(auth_key); Response -> Data: data1:xxxx, data2, xxxx, data3:etc...

Use JSON in generating your data, it's a simple way to pass data with client-server connection :)

If you have any questions about setting up a simple RESTful service, please feel free to ask :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer ... I solved my problem with the server cookies.(if this wasnt on hold i would have posted my answer as it is alternative for anyone who is struggling with vpn connection to the server )